# How to put a constant as refs in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have an Icon like below

```
<Icon
  name='heart' ref='l{item.id}' size={30} color='#FF216B' 
  onPress={() => this.loveLeash(item.id)} />
```

As you can see, I want to make a `ref` for this icon including a `const` and a letter.
This is important to do because there are hundreds of these icons on my screen(picture below) and I need to select particular one. So, I am planning to use `refs`. 
[image: This is how the icons are placed in posts]

But, the code I have given just return the same text I wrote. 
It doesn't apply the const I added.

I am totally new to react native. Just playing with it for a few days. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What is your purpose in adding refs to every item? Can you say any use cases?

Comment: there are hundreds of these icons. I need to select particular one from them

Answer (score 0):

[please go through the react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

[image]

Comment: Sorry but please read my question. My problem is difficult. There are hundreds of these icons on the same screen. But if you have any idea to select a particular icon from them without using ``refs`` that will be helpful

Comment: just pass a callback onLikedClicked() with a ItemId, don't createRef for that.